# Including a PHP File: cURL, Pathing, and Security Risks

Tags: php, security, curl

So I have heard a lot about cURL having security risks. I need to know if what I am doing can have security risks, and if so, how can I prevent it.

I have my own VPS (Virtual Private Server) through Host Gator.

Basically I am trying to include a file from a different domain. Both domains are in the same server. I tried to use the absolute path to include the file, but I keep getting a permission denied error.

This is my code to include the file using cURL:

```
$url = "http://mydomain.com/include.php";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Is there a security risk doing this? If so, how can I prevent this security risk?

In addition, how can I set permissions on the domain so I can include a PHP file from another domain on the same server?

Comment: There is no special "security risk" in this, since you don't do anything with the result you fetch from that domain (which actually makes me wonder why you do it in the first place...). There _would_ be a security risk if you _would_ use the result inside your code or rendered page, since it can contain all sorts of attack code. You simply should not do that, unless you ultimately trust that other domain.

Comment: Remember that when you "include" ( it's not `including`) file via cURL, you do not get in result PHP code which can be used on your side,but you get plan text result - html, plain text etc. cURL is just like a web browser call. So if you have any clases, functions etc in `include.php`, you won't be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading data from different domain but same server you can simply use include and path but you can neither grab php file with url nor its recommended.

Comment: How can I use include path without getting a permission deny error? How can I set the permission?

Comment: you can give group permission to the folder of userid under which your apache is running.
Google about changing owner group of folder in linux. Its linux's chown cmd